# Bootstrap collapse not working when using dynamic id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue when creating dynamic id for bootstrap collapse.
First when I click on any topic which is in ng-repeat it should collapse and give me the question list.

The problem here is when I click on the first topic it collapse but when i click on second topic the first topic collapse is getting the second topic question list data

Html:

```
<div class="topic-div">
                    <p class="topic-heading">Topics</p>
                </div>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="topics in oJdDetails.topics" class="topic-li"  ng-click="fngetQList(topics,$index)">
                        <p class="topics-p"> {{topics}}</p>
                        <ul uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
                            <li ng-repeat="value in aQuestionList">{{value.quesList.quesListName}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Js:

```
$scope.fngetQList = function(topics, index) {
            debugger;
            $scope.isCollapsed = true;
            $scope.displayQList = true;
            $scope.sTopics = topics;
            $scope.index = index;
            getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQList(topics).then(function(response) {
                $scope.aQuestionList = response;
                console.log($scope.aQuestionList);
            });
        };
```

I don't understand how to make it work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using plain bootstrap library which will not work with angularjs.
Try with https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse

Comment: when i use uib-collapsehow to differentiate the dynamically generated topics data?

Comment: uib-collapse will allow you to use angular expressions.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my updated code and guide me how to do dynamic angular expression for not getting same data loaded when i click on specific topic

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid using jQuery with Angular especially for Bootstrap. Angular's UI team has written the Angular wrapper for Bootstrap.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Use this library instead. You don't need the jQuery for this. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse

This uses the Bootstrap's CSS file and the Javascript part is provided by the Angular so you don't need to use jQuery for it.

Angular in itself is a big enough Javascript library so don't bloat your application by installing jQuery as well.

Comment: Agarwal 
I have updated my code with uib-collapse but i m unable to figure out how to load it dynamic data when i click specific topic